# Using time.time() in Python to measure time elapsed for code segments consumes significant time itself

Tags: python-3.x, time, runtime, profiling, ubuntu-20.04

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

In my code written in Python, I am using `time.time()` to calculate the time taken by various parts of the code. So, I have multiple blocks as shown below in my overall code:

```
start_time = time.time()
# some code
end_time = time.time()
```

Now, since there are multiple blocks as above in the overall code (because I need to measure time consumed by various code segments, and not just the overall time cosumption), so what I noticed is that the `time.time()` statements itself consume significant time that the overall runtime of the code shoots from say 10 secs to 15 secs. I was expecting that statement `time.time()` would consume insignificant amount of time such that there would be negligible affect on the overall runtime. Could you please help me to tackle this issue ?

I wanted to see what amount of time a code block consumes as compared to the overall runtime. But if the overall runtime gets significantly affected due to `time.time()` statements, then there is this problem.

Also, I noticed that the sum of times consumed by each code block is way less than total time consumed. So, I am clueless what eats up some time duration, where does it go?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is expected behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

```
start_time = time.time()
#Code
total_time = str((time.time() - start))
```

Or if you want to get multiple times:

```
start_time = time.time()
#some code
checkpoint1 = str((time.time() - start))
#more code
checkpoint2 = str((time.time() - start))
#...
```

Comment: It seems that you could not understand my question. I request you to read the full question.

Comment: Yes I understood your question but that error does not happen for me. Maybe it depends on your internet connection and the overall runtime of code.

Comment: There is no role of internet connection. I do not need to use internet connection to execute my code. @BattleCalls

Comment: Oh my bad. I use a program that requires a good connection because it doesn't only execute Python. Maybe the `time` module just contains a lot of code and takes a few extra seconds to execute in your program. As I said I do not have the same issue as you.